# Solve the following definite integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2dx}{({1-x^2})^2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Solve the following integral:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{∞}\frac{x^2dx}{({1-x^2})^2}$$

I know that substituting some trigonometric functions may help. 
But I was not able to solve. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: The integrand has a pole of order $2$ in $x = 1$, it is not integrable. Was the denominator maybe $(1+x^2)^2$?

Comment: Try x = sint Works fine, Rafik. Show us what you got

Comment: Daniel, are you hinting at complex integration? I suspect the poster doens't know that yet :)

Comment: @imranfat I'm not hinting at anything yet, just pointing out that the integral is infinite due to the pole.

Comment: Perhaps pole suggests complex analysis, @DanielFischer . It would be enough to point out that the integral does *not* converge due to the point $\,x=1\;$, in whose neighborhood the function is "badly" unbounded...

Comment: @DonAntonio Aha, that didn't occur to me. We called the zeros of the denominator of a rational function (where the numerator hasn't a zero) poles already in school, long before we learned about complex numbers or even calculus, so I didn't associate the term with complex methods.

Comment: Geee, integral diverges, of course. Didn't even notice that. Well that changes a lot.

Comment: A moral is: check convergence before you start worrying about trig substitutions and other such tricks.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\large\mbox{In case the}\ -\ \mbox{switch to}\ +$:

> $$
> \mu > 0\,,
> \quad
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 + \mu x^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
> =
> {1 \over \sqrt{\mu\,}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 + x^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
> =
> {1 \over \sqrt{\mu\,}}\,{\pi \over 2}
> $$

Derivate respect of $\ds{\mu}$ in both members:
$$
-\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over \left(1 + \mu x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
=
-\,{1 \over 2\mu^{3/2}}\,{\pi \over 2}
$$

> Set $\mu = 1$:
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over \left(1 + x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
> =
> {\pi \over 4}
> $$

$\large\mbox{With the}\ -\ \mbox{sign, we'll assume it's a 'principal value'}\ \pp
$:
\begin{align}
\pp\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x&
=\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
+\int_{1 + \epsilon}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
+\int_{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}^{0}{1/x^{2} \over \left(1 - 1/x^{2}\right)^{2}}
\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
+\int_{0}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}
\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\bracks{%
2\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
+\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}
{x^{2} \over \left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{2}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}
The second integral $\ds{\stackrel{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to}{1 \over 4}}$
while the first term behaves as $\ds{{1 \over 2\epsilon}}$ when
$\ds{\epsilon \gtrsim 0}$ such that 'even' the "principal value" diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}dx$

$=\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}dx+\int_1^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\tanh^2x}{(1-\tanh^2x)^2}d(\tanh x)+\int_\infty^0\dfrac{\coth^2x}{(1-\coth^2x)^2}d(\coth x)$

$=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\text{sech}^2x\tanh^2x}{\text{sech}^4x}dx+\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\text{csch}^2x\coth^2x}{\text{csch}^4x}dx$

$=\int_0^\infty(\sinh^2x+\cosh^2x)~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\cosh2x~dx$

$=\left[\dfrac{\sinh2x}{2}\right]_0^\infty$

$=+\infty$

$\therefore\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}dx$ is divergent.

Comment: So you wrote $\infty = \infty + \infty$. How does that help?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Shown that it is divergent.

Comment: Considering what else has been written on this page, at least _spell it out_.